# Monit config update with reload leaving zombie processes

Tags: monitoring, monit, zombie-process

We ran into a rare problem here I hope. We are having monit for running background jobs. In AWS Opsworks, we configured chef recipes to run in deploy cycle. Those recipes will update every time the deployment happened. But there is a problem whenever we update the `monitrc` file dynamically and issue `monit reload` command.

Issue goes like this (reproducible):

- Initially `monitrc` file is having job configs say J1, J2, J3, J4.
- Now update the `monitrc` file with J1, J2, J3 configs only.
- Now run `monit reload`. This will simply reload the configuration and updates with J1, J2, J3 jobs only.

Here comes the issue. After this reload `monit reload` is not clearing the J4 job. Now we trigger a deploy. New code will be there in all J1, J2, J3 jobs because all the recipes issues commands like `monit restart <J_ID>`. But not in J4 because J4 is no more monitored by `monit`. Leaving the J4 job running background with old source code.

So if anybody faced this problem before, please help me with your solution.